# multiple thread app crash, log said Unable to restore previously selected frame

Tags: iphone, multithreading

interface file:

```
    // ...    

    UITextView *statusTextView_;
    UITableView *accountListTableView_;
    NSMutableArray *accountList_;

    NSString *lastStatus_;

    // ...

@property (retain) UITextView *statusTextView;
@property (retain) UITableView *accountListTableView;
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *accountList;

@property (retain) NSString *lastStatus;

// ...
```

implement file:

```
// ...

@synthesize statusTextView=statusTextView_;
@synthesize accountListTableView=accountListTableView_;
@synthesize accountList=accountList_;

@synthesize lastStatus=lastStatus_;

- (void)aBtnTapAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.lastStatus release];
    NSString *buf = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:self.statusTextView.text];
    self.lastStatus = buf;
    [buf release];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in self.accountList) {
        if (TRUE == [[dict objectForKey:@"checked"] boolValue]) {
            NSString *selectorName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@:", [dict objectForKey:@"name"]];
            SEL sel = NSSelectorFromString(selectorName);
            [selectorName release];
            if (YES == [self respondsToSelector:sel]) {
                [self performSelectorInBackground:sel withObject:dict];                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

selectorName is one of followings

```
- (void)sina:(NSDictionary *)info
{    
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    SinaController *sina = [[FooController alloc] 
                                 initWithUsername:[info objectForKey:@"username"]
                                 andPasswd:[info objectForKey:@"passwd"]];
    code = [sina post:self.lastStatus];    
    [sina release]; 

    [pool release];     
}

- (void)qq:(NSDictionary *)info
{    
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    QQController *qq = [[FooController alloc] 
                                 initWithUsername:[info objectForKey:@"username"]
                                 andPasswd:[info objectForKey:@"passwd"]];
    code = [qq post:self.lastStatus];    
    [qq release]; 

    [pool release];     
}
```

app always crash in qq or sina thread, log said:

```
warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.
```

Testing environment: MacOS10.6.7, XCode4 & Simulator.

I can't find any useful information by XCode Product -> analyze or Profile -> memory leaks.
I'm following Memory Management Programming Guide and try my best to fix it, but it still crash.

- What's wrong with my code, why it crash ?
- What are best practices that Objective-C coder when writing multiple thread pragram ?

Thanks for reply.

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning: check_safe_call: could not restore current frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295295/warning-check-safe-call-could-not-restore-current-frame)

Answer (score -1):

By releasing using the dot notation, you are over-releasing.

```
[self.lastStatus release];
```

should just be

```
self.lastStatus = nil;
```

Otherwise you are calling a release on lastStatus and then when you assign the new value using

```
self.lastStatus = buf;
```

Then this is first calling a release on the already released object.  For more information read up about properties, the dot notation and memory management.

Comment: Calling `[self.lastStatus release]` Drops the retain count by one, then calling `self.lastStatus = buf` first releases lastStatus which drops the retain count by another one - Therefore it has been released twice?

Comment: @Remover - No problem. Could you remove the downvote on the answer (if it was you who placed it there)?

Comment: @nick... wasn't me. I did the first one. You can't change it unless the answer is changed. So, I upvoted your comment.

Comment: @Remover - thanks. Appreciate that. I was referring to second down vote. Have a feeling it was someone being bitter because I downvoted one of their answers! If not, second downvoter please comment on why you downvoted this